# Как оптимизировать работу PHP скриптов?

Tags: php

После заполнения `html` формы отправляю пользователя на стр. `"Спасибо"` а данные на файл обработчик, `НО` проблема в том что пользователя `не перебрасывает` на "спасибо" пока не отработают скрипты на стр обработчике, а это долго, там много всяких рассылок.

Как можно `сразу` пользователя отправлять на стр. "Спасибо" не дожидаясь пока отработают все скрипты?

```js
//Отправка формы
  $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e){ 
  // Во время отправки формы отключаем кнопку
  $(this).find('[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true).html('Идет отправка...');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'send.php',
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function($response) {
        document.location = 'spasibo.php';
     console.log('done');
    })
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Отправьте Ajax запрос и не дожидаясь ответа выполните редирект.

```
//Отправка формы
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e){ 
   // Во время отправки формы отключаем кнопку
   $(this).find('[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true).html('Идет    отправка...');

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'send.php',
       data: $(this).serialize()
   })

   document.location = 'spasibo.php';

   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно отправить ответ, а уже потом доделывать всю остальную работу. Вот например вот так https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/middlewares.html#finish-middleware

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/285035)

Comment: Чем "можно отправить ответ, а уже потом доделывать всю остальную работу" не ответ на вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Вынесете `document.location` за пределы `ajax` (чтоб был перед `return false;`), а в сам `ajax` добавьте `url: 'send.php', timeout: 500,`

---

P.S. но это все костыльный способ, лучше, чтоб ваш скрипт ставил задание рассылки в очередь, а демон бы его выполнял.